# Audrio Studio can not invoke virtual device

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to invoke a virtual device created through the Android Studio AVD manager, I always get the error message "Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741701 (0xC000007B)".  Not sure what does this mean.

Answer (score 0):

in my case Avast had deleted my Emulator files. You can check your virus vault for quarantined files.

The files I was looking for where at: "ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER"/emulator/qemu/

To find out where your ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER is, you can enter AndroidStudio, File, Project Structure, SDK Location. There you will find it.

There you should have two folders: "windows-x86_64" and "windows-x86", each one with six ".exe" files inside.

If you happen to find missing files or folders, like I did, try to recover them from antivirus vault, if it fails try to copy both folders from another computer, and if it fails again try to uninstall AndroidStudio and reinstalling.

If it was AntiVirus related, do white-list the whole SDK folder in your antivirus program before running the emulater, otherwise it will get deleted again.

Hope it helps!

Best regards,
    Federico.